# Does fit() overwrite the current fitted and trained state of the model? (Keras)

Tags: python, keras

I'm training a time series forecasting LSTM-model in Keras.
When I save the trained model and reload it, to train it on different data (so the weights get better and can predict several types of data), is it alright to:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=60, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
# make predictions
y_pred_train = np.squeeze(model.predict(x_train), axis=(1,))
y_pred_val = np.squeeze(model.predict(x_val), axis=(1,))

# save whole model
model.save('lstm_model.h5')

# load and fit model
loaded_model = load_model('lstm_model.h5')

loaded_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=60, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

I wonder if the training starts all over again and the trained status is gone after fitting in a second time.

Thank you for helping! :)

Comment: Efectively, the fit will be done with the already trained model, (i.e. it will 'continue' the training, not starting again).

Comment: @ebeneditos alright, if that is so, then I can continue with this approach!